# Noise on TL074 / TL084 but not on LM324

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, signal, noise

I made a circuit that modifies a signal so it can be safely read by an ADC.
I'm using an op amp to shift the signal +2.5V so I can measure AC. When I do this shift another signal appears. About 40mV amplitude, 8kHz freq. But only if the op amp is TL074 or TL084. If using LM324 I don't get that. I also don't get that signal if I'm not using the +2.5V offset.

What could be causing that?

[image: Noise signal]

[image]

[Link to schematic](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rsmzut8n2ewds1s/schematic.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: Always try and include a picture rather than a link to a pdf. People are not going to through pdfs to find something that should have been presented in the body of the question.

Comment: If you measure your supply rail, some ripple that follows the noise you are seeing ?

Comment: Your circuit is difficult to follow because there is so much detail and it's not clear which connection has the noise.

Comment: Could it be that the LM324 cuts the noise because it has a lower bandwidth than the other two op-amps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The few tens of mV noise is almost surely caused by the 7660, which has an operating frequency of around 10kHz.

The PSRR of the TL084 is much worse (14dB) than the LM324.. Have a look at the actual ripple on the negative supply and related layout.

Comment: Adding a 220uF cap on the output of the 7660 definitely improves it, but there's still some noise left. Adding a big 1000uF cap seems a bit overkill. Any other things I could try? Will get my hands on an oscilloscope in a few hours.

Comment: ESR matters. Try a 1uF~10uF ceramic in parallel. Layout could also be an issue if it's really bad.

Comment: I am a complete beginner at PCB making. The layout is similar to the schematic. I kept the caps close to the sources, and there are about 4-5cm from the 7660 to the op amp.
I also have another signal (a lot more spiky, can be seen in the screenshot) ~100Hz, that is 100-200mV (on the LM324), <100mV (TL074) and it disappears is I touch the GND. Could it be related to the 50Hz mains? I'm powering the board with a 12V switching power supply.

Comment: Most likely the 100Hz is related to the mains. Layout issues often involve the way currents flow in ground connections.